# How do I add leaderboard feature of OpenFeint in android?

Tags: android, openfeint

I am developing a game in android, by extending a class with view. I have integrated OpenFeint in it by studying the [tutorial provided on the OpenFeint site](http://support.openfeint.com/dev/getting-started-with-of-android-1-10-2-integrate-openfeint-in-your-game/), but I am not able to add the leaderboard feature in my app. How can I achieve it?

My game class is like this

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {  

Intent i;

Grapic g;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);           

    setContentView(new Grapic(this));
```

and Grapic is a class which extends view and where scoring is done with touch events.

Comment: Have you added a leaderboard in the openfeint developer website?  You have to set it up first and then, in theory, the openfeint client sees that it's there and lets you use it.

Comment: First sorry for late reply Tetrad ,  yes i have set up a leaderboard for my game in openfeint developer website , and i also have its id but i was not able to understand where to use that code of tutorial

Comment: even i am stuck at the same problem..... i think after enabling the openfeint feature...they will provide some means to access it..

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting stuck trying to add OpenFeint (or now GREE) leaderboards to your Android game, then take a look at [Swarm](http://swarmconnect.com) (aka SwarmConnect).  It's incredibly easy and straight forward to implement and some pretty popular games are already using it ([Logo Quiz](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=logos.quiz.companies.game) with 10 million to 50 million downloads is one example).